# Запрос представления Django через JS по таймеру

Tags: javascript, python, django

Задача состоит в обновлении значений конкретных HTML тегов по таймеру, без перезагрузки всей страницы, код ниже запрашивает представление Django в цикле JS.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from opc_app import views
from opc_app.views import *

urlpatterns = [
url(r'Main_DateTime/', DateTime_main_func),
url(r'Template_DateTime/', Actual_DateTime_template_func, name="Template"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render    
import datetime
from datetime import time    

from django.http import HttpResponse

def Actual_DateTime_template_func (request):
    now_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    out_values = {
    "DateTime": now_date,
    "Time": now_date.time(), }

    return render (request, "Actual_DateTime_template.html", context = out_values)

def DateTime_main_func (request):
    return render (request, "Main_DateTime.html")
```

**Actual_DateTime_template.html**

```
{{ DateTime }}
<br>
{{ Time }}
```

**Main_DateTime.html**

```
<body>

   <p class="Rand_Time"></p>
   <p class="Rand_Time"></p>
   <p class="Rand_Time"></p>
   <p class="Rand_Time"></p>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  Call_Update_func();

function Call_Update_func() {

  $('.Rand_Time').load("{% url 'Template' %}");  
  setTimeout(Call_Update_func, 1000);
}
});

</script>
</body>
```

Проблема в том, что нужно вывести в каждый тег разные переменные Django, если выбирать по id получается на каждую переменную придется писать функцию, посоветуйте как можно организовать оптимальную выборку данных, спасибо!

Comment: "нужно вывести в каждый тег разные переменные" - подробности?

Comment: Пробовал использовать метод GetElementById, но необходимо для каждого тега создавать отдельный шаблон, можете посоветовать более корректное решение?

Comment: $(document.getElementById("Date")).load("{% url 'Template' %}");
$(document.getElementById("Time")).load("{% url 'Template' %}");

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему подгрузкой строки таблицы уже с переменными

**Actual_DateTime_template.html**

```
<tr>
   <td >{{ DateTime }}</td>
   <td >{{ Time }}</td>
   <td ></td>
   <td ></td>

</tr>
```